# How To Convert "EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm aaa" DateTime Format to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" DateTime Format in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am working in a Flutter Project using Dart where I have a String DateTime as `Fri, Sep 30, 2022 01:10 PM` that I want to convert in DateTime object with `2022-09-30 13:10:00` format.

For this, I tried the below snippet...

```
String inputDateTime = "Fri, Sep 30, 2022 01:10 PM";
DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
String formatted_inputDateTime = formatter.format(inputDateTime);
DateTime inputDateTime_DT = DateTime.parse(formatted_inputDateTime);
```

But getting error and now getting my required DateTime object.

How to fix this up to get required format of DateTime Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, try this:

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm aaa")
        .parse('Fri, Sep 30, 2022 01:10 PM');
String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(tempDate);
print('formattedDate = $formattedDate'); //2022-09-30 13:10:00
```

Comment: Your answer is 90% correct but the output time is `01:10:00` where it should be `13:10:00` as the output is 24 hour format converted from PM input. How to fix it?

Comment: Check out my update